# Image sequence preview and animation is empty

Tags: rendering

I'm a beginner and just started learning Blender, so I followed Blender Guru's donut tutorial to the end, but in the animation part, when I add an image/sequence in the preview, it shows nothing, it's completely blank. So I thought let's see if the final animation looks different, but the animation was also completely black.

[image]

So I asked on reddit and got no response except one that said to check if the render is not actually blank by opening it in other apps and checking if the current frames move when you play the animation, as well as your resolution. So I opened it in Photoshop and Krita and there was no problem. I also checked the current frames that moves when the animation moves, but my resolution is set to "None" and I can't click on it or edit it.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It's been a while, I don't know if you still have this issue, but I had the same problem following the same tutorial. I figured out what happened to the images:

When exporting your frames, be sure to select *OpenEXR* format and not *OpenEXR Multilayer* (which comes before in the list for whatever reason). The output seems to be the same (same .exr files) but from what I understood while trying to open them with another software, it messes up the alpha channel.